# $2 \times 3$ Null Space Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Find all $2 \times 3$ matrices $A$ whose null space is the plane $3x − 5y − z = 0$.

I know the vector for null space is $(3,-5,-1)$ but I'm not sure how to use that to find all the diferent $2 \times 3$ matrices within that space.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
You want:
$$
\begin {bmatrix}
a_1&b_1&c_1\\
a_2&b_2&c_2\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin {bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z\\
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin {bmatrix}
a_1x+b_1y+c_1z\\
a_2x+b_2y+c_2z\\
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin {bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
for $x$, $y$, $z$ such that $3x-5y-z=0$. So what can be $a_1,b_1,c_1$? ( and $a_2,b_2,c_2$)?